# Real time UML class diagramming tool for concurrent editors?

Tags: uml, real-time, collaboration, class-diagram

I'm looking for something similar to Google Docs, where you can work with other team members simultaneously for class diagramming.

I've looked into Creately and Gliffy, but neither support concurrent editors for a real time project.

Does anyone know of any good applications supporting good diagramming as well as concurrent edits?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a model and create UML diagrams views from your model. If you save your model and your diagrams on SVN or CVS then you are able to share diagrams on multiple locations with multiple teams.
I am using Omondo EclipseUML for a  vary large Java EE project and we are able to share diagrams between India, UK, France and USA for the same project.

The trick we use is to save our model at the root of our project in Eclipse. It means that each time we made a change it is saved on our company SVN.

The other trick to make life easier and avoid concurrent SVN connection is to let each team develop its own piece of software like a project. We then extend and link all projects at code level and finally create a single model composed by all project which are each one a submodel of the main model.

We can share class UML diagrams among our teams and always have an up to date model. If the code changes then our model is automatically updated. All our diagrams also.
Really cool, no more painful / useless Model driven development where there is an obligation to generate code from a model which is as stupid as generating HTML from a word document. Once generated you can put all the code in the bin because not possible to reuse it !!

We therefore only use class diagrams as a view of our model which is life synchronized with the code. The code is the core of my application. I can create code with the UML class diagram or by hand codding. Our UML class diagrams is only now a live documentation of our project. It means we avoid wasting time on modeling and just use what we really need to be more efficient in order to write a better code, better architecture and have up to date perfect project documentation of the implementation stage at code level.

Answer (score -1):

Cacoo.com is awesome. Seriously... It's awesome and supports multiple editors in real time. It's the visio for google docs